# Programmatically fetching/updating google calendar data online on iOS EventKit

Tags: ios, calendar, gmail, fetch, eventkit

My iOS app (iOS11) reads events from an iPhone calendar using EventKit, which works fine. The calendar I'm reading from is from a (free) gmail account. A Google account on iOS does not support pushing data but only fetching. Calendar events are hence only updated when I open the built-in iPhone Calendar app.

In my app, I continuously display the current events of the day. A timer updates the display of events.

My problem is the following: If I change some events in my calendar on calendar.google.com, the changes are not going to appear in my app, only after I first go to the built-in Calendar app to fetch the data and then switch back to my app.

My question: is there a way using EventKit or another mechanism to force-fetch the calendar data online as happens when I open the Calendar app?

PS: I already tried adding the gmail account using Exchange, which should support Push, but it doesn't work for free gmail accounts.

PPS: If I create a new event using EventKit it gets directly pushed to google and is immediately visible on calendar.google.com. That's great but doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RefereshSources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507421-refreshsourcesifnecessary)  Use this - you can call force referesh on eventstore after adding event .

EventStore.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Although it takes a minute or so until it updates. In the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507421-refreshsourcesifnecessary) it says "Use this method to pull new data from remote sources if the local data is out of date." Do you know how it determines if the data is "out of date"?